# How do I remove the "Please Reconnect Controller" Dialog on XBOX using XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, xbox360

In my XNA game, if a player disconnects controller #1, a dialog comes up that says "Please reconnect controller". They can continue playing if they start using controller 2 and I would like to programtically dismiss the dialog in that case. I have found nothing in my online searching and pouring through XNA documentation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that message is built into the Xbox 360 firmware, and hence there is no way to control or dismiss it from within the XNA Framework.

Since profiles are associated with controllers on the Xbox 360, that message will always appear when a game is running and a controller is disconnected with a profile still signed in. You should be able to verify this by signing a profile in using another of your controllers, then disconnecting that controller.

You may want to check out [this thread](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/33750/334130.aspx) over at the XNA Forums for more information on how your game could respond to controller disconnects.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203901%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) also provides some information on handling controller disconnects.

Comment: It's just by design. Even games developed with the full SDK can't dismiss that message.